# Jsoup in Java return always the same page with different URL - SCRAPING website

Tags: java, url, caching, jsoup

```
public void conectUrl() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        product= new ArrayList<>();

        String url = "https://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/pages/category.aspx?cat=campanhas#/?page=1&sf=Revelance";

         page = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("JSoup scraper").get();
        

        //get actual page

        Elements paginaAtu=page.getElementsByClass("_actualPage");
        paginaAtual=Integer.parseInt(paginaAtu.attr("value"));

        
        
        //get Total Pages
        Elements nextPage=page.getElementsByClass("_actualTotalPages");
        numPaginas =Integer.parseInt(nextPage.attr("value"));
        
        
        for(paginaAtual=1;paginaAtual<numPaginas;paginaAtual++) {
            getProductInfo("https://www.continente.pt/stores/continente/pt-pt/public/pages/category.aspx?cat=campanhas#/?page="+paginaAtual+"&sf=Revelance");
            
        }
    }
```

Always return the same resul with different URL. I already searched about jsoup cache , i am not the first person doing this question, however nobody says how to resolve the situation. In theory, JSoup doesn't cache url pages...

I already did the code "sleep" during 30 seconds to load the new URL however still not working, return always the same result.

Anybody can help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you use 'Jsoup scraper' as your user agent? Why don't you use your browser's user agent?

Comment: It's resolved , i can't use Jsoup to navigate on webpage, jsoup is only to inspect the current URL, so to resolve this I must use a library like Selenium that works fine with my browser to interact with the page and give the result as argument to JSOUP. Thank you guys!

Comment: Not strictly true @MdaCosta. Your browser issues/handles HTTP requests. JSoup behaves similarly to a browser but is much more basic. If you know what to look for you can typically use JSoup/HtmlUnit + some know-how to construct a scraper that will work. Saying that, its hard to answer your question without knowing what `getProductInfo` is doing